# How to execute custom Splittable DoFn in parallel

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am trying to develop a custom I/O connector for Apache Beam, written in Python. According to the [official guideline](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-overview/), Splittable DoFn (SDF) is the framework of choice in my case.

I tried to run the pseudocode in the [SDF programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns), however, I failed to execute the pipeline in parallel. Below is a working example.

**Dummy data**

```
myfile = open('test_beam.txt', 'w')
for i in range(0, 1000):
    myfile.write("%s\n" % i)

myfile.close
```

**Pipeline**

Make sure to replace `DUMMY_FILE` with the absolute path of `test_beam.txt`.

```
import argparse
import logging
import os

import apache_beam as beam

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions


from time import sleep
import random

from apache_beam.io.restriction_trackers import OffsetRange

DUMMY_FILE = absolute_path_to_dummy_data_file

class FileToWordsRestrictionProvider(beam.transforms.core.RestrictionProvider
                                     ):
    def initial_restriction(self, file_name):
        return OffsetRange(0, os.stat(file_name).st_size)

    def create_tracker(self, restriction):
        return beam.io.restriction_trackers.OffsetRestrictionTracker(
            offset_range=self.initial_restriction(file_name=DUMMY_FILE))

    def restriction_size(self, element, restriction):
        return restriction.size()


class FileToWordsFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(
        self,
        file_name,
        # Alternatively, we can let FileToWordsFn itself inherit from
        # RestrictionProvider, implement the required methods and let
        # tracker=beam.DoFn.RestrictionParam() which will use self as
        # the provider.
            tracker=beam.DoFn.RestrictionParam(FileToWordsRestrictionProvider())):
        with open(file_name) as file_handle:
            file_handle.seek(tracker.current_restriction().start)
            while tracker.try_claim(file_handle.tell()):
                yield read_next_record(file_handle=file_handle)


def read_next_record(file_handle):
    line_number = file_handle.readline()
    logging.info(line_number)
    sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    logging.info(f'iam done {line_number}')


def run(args, pipeline_args, file_name):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        execute_pipeline(args, p, file_name)


def execute_pipeline(args, p, file_name):
    _ = (
          p |
          'Create' >> beam.Create([file_name]) |
          'Read File' >> beam.ParDo(FileToWordsFn(file_name=file_name))
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    """Build and run the pipeline."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # to be added later

    args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    file_name = DUMMY_FILE
    run(args, pipeline_args, file_name)
```

The SDF is taken from the first example [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#a-basic-sdf), however, I had to fix a few things (e.g., define `restriction_size` and a minor misplacement of `()`). Furthermore, I introduced a random sleep in `read_next_record` to check whether the pipeline is executed in parallel (which it is not apparently).

There is probably a mistake in the way I constructed the pipeline? I would expect to use my SDF as the very first step in the pipeline, but doing so results in `AttributeError: 'PBegin' object has no attribute 'windowing'`. To circumvent this issue, I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703925/pbegin-object-has-no-attribute-windowing-while-running-beam-pipeline) and added created a PCollection containing the input `file_name`.

What is the correct way to execute an SDF within a pipeline in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Beam `DoFn`s (including `SplittableDoFn`s) operate on an input `PCollection`. For `SplittableDoFn`, the input is usually a `PCollection` of source configs (for example, input files). When executing a `SplittableDoFn` the Beam runner is able to parallelize the execution of even a single input element by isolating parts of the input read using the `RestrictionTracker`. So for a file, this would mean that you might have workers running in parallel that read data from the same file but at different offsets.

So your implementation seems correct and should already facilitate parallel execution for a Beam runner.

Answer (score 0):

[Splittable DoFns](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns) of apache beam allows create a custom config to  runner initiated splits, my case I had to process a big file where all content don't have separators and these were in one line and dataflow don't scalled. I used beam.transforms.core.RestrictionProvider, with the function split, where I specificed the number of parts for read the file and with this config when I ran the job dataflow used varios workers and the time of process reduced a lot.

```
class FileToLinesRestrictionProvider(beam.transforms.core.RestrictionProvider):
    def initial_restriction(self, file_name):
        return OffsetRange(0, size_file) #6996999736   #43493
        #return OffsetRange(0, os.stat(file_name).st_size)

    def create_tracker(self, restriction):
        # return beam.io.restriction_trackers.OffsetRestrictionTracker(
        #     offset_range=self.initial_restriction(file_name=rutaFile_Test))
        return beam.io.restriction_trackers.OffsetRestrictionTracker(restriction)
    
    def split(self, file_name, restriction):
        # Configuración para leer el archivo por partes
        bundle_ranges = calcular_segmentos_lectura(tamFila, tam_segmentos, size_file)
        for start, stop in bundle_ranges:
            yield OffsetRange(start, stop)

    def restriction_size(self, element, restriction):
        #print(restriction.size())
        return restriction.size()


class FileToLinesFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(
        self,
        file_name,
        # Alternatively, we can let FileToWordsFn itself inherit from
        # RestrictionProvider, implement the required methods and let
        # tracker=beam.DoFn.RestrictionParam() which will use self as
        # the provider.
        tracker=beam.DoFn.RestrictionParam(FileToLinesRestrictionProvider())):
        with FileSystems.open(file_name) as file_handle:
            file_handle.seek(tracker.current_restriction().start)
            print(tracker.current_restriction())
            while tracker.try_claim(file_handle.tell()):
                #print(file_handle.tell())
                yield  file_handle.read(tamFila)

def calcular_segmentos_lectura(
size_line,
tam_segmentos,
tam_file):
    
""" Basado en el tamaño del archivo y tamaños de las lineas divide en partes de acuerdo
    a los parametros de entrada
    Retorna array con los caracteres que deben procesar en cada paso
"""
num_lineas = int(tam_file /size_line)
valor_segmento = int(num_lineas / tam_segmentos)
valor_segmento = valor_segmento * size_line
print(valor_segmento)
segmentos_ranges = []
valorAnterior = 0
for i in range(tam_segmentos):
    start = valorAnterior
    stop_position = (valorAnterior + (valor_segmento))
    valorAnterior = stop_position 
    if (i + 1) == tam_segmentos:
        stop_position = tam_file
    segmentos_ranges.append((start, stop_position))

return segmentos_ranges
```

This example help me a lot [url](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/testing/synthetic_pipeline.py)